# Merge request dto and response dto in one dto

Tags: spring, dto

I notice that quite often I need a separate DTO for requests and responses, because requests have added validation constraints and reponses usually contain more data.

For example:

```
package be.ambrassade.jeugdlink.model.request;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

public class AnswerRequest {
    @Size(min = 10, max = 1000)
    @NotNull
    private String message;


    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

And:

```
package be.ambrassade.jeugdlink.model.response;

import java.sql.Timestamp;

public class AnswerResponse  {
    private int id;
    private String message;
    private UserResponse user;
    private Timestamp postedOn;
    private boolean chosen;
    private Short likes;
    private boolean userLikedAnswer;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public UserResponse getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(UserResponse user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public Timestamp getPostedOn() {
        return postedOn;
    }

    public void setPostedOn(Timestamp postedOn) {
        this.postedOn = postedOn;
    }

    public boolean isChosen() {
        return chosen;
    }

    public void setChosen(boolean chosen) {
        this.chosen = chosen;
    }

    public Short getLikes() {
        return likes;
    }

    public void setLikes(Short likes) {
        this.likes = likes;
    }

    public boolean isUserLikedAnswer() {
        return userLikedAnswer;
    }

    public void setUserLikedAnswer(boolean userLikedAnswer) {
        this.userLikedAnswer = userLikedAnswer;
    }
}
```

Is there any way to combine them in one general DTO for Answers and perhaps do the validation and property filtering in one way or another? I have to add that quite some data is generated by the database layer, say for example the id, postedOn timestamp, etc.

Comment: Using them as a seperated objects is better. You always be sure about the input and output. Why do you want to do in that way?

Comment: @uğurtaş As a way to learn more specific ways of doing it that I'm not familiar about. I saw that for example Jackson annotations can be used to call different serialization classes, so maybe that would a different way to go.

Answer (score 1):

What I generally do is have generic Request and Response DTOs while keeping the entity objects as per the business model. The sample ResponseDTO would look like below in this approach.

```
public class ResponseDTO {

//SUCCESS / FAILURE
private String status;
//failure message if any
private String message;

//response pay load. eg. AnswerDTO
private Object payload;


}
```